# how to show square root symbol in php code using gd library?

Tags: php, gd

I am now dealing with a mathematical problem with my codes. I have second degree equation , for example , ax^2+bx+c=z .

If we have to find the value of 'X', we have the eqution , x=(-b +/- root(b^2-4ac))/2a.

The main headache is that i've to show the square root symbol in image using gd library. But i dont know how to show this equation using proper mathematical(i mean using square root symbol etc.) in the image using gd functions.

Is there a way for doing it?

Comment: Nice. What have you tried so far? I'd +1 this if I see some effort

Comment: im a newbie in GD lib, actually i've googled for the solution for the last two days, but i didnt get the proper solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work in imagettftext -  √. To do it Mac you hold Alt (option) + J

You can use an image (BLOB) from a mysql database as wellas well as string data and it will auto detect it and creates a GD resource based on it. The image has to be supported but i'm sure the square root symbol is. Good luck I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Most TrueType fonts include a square-root symbol (√) at U+221A. Starting with that you can draw that into your image with `imagettftext()`, then fill in the rest around it. You'll need to fiddle with the font sizes to get the whole equation to look right, and since GD isn't a maths graphics package this whole thing will be a matter of trial and error.

Comment: i've an idea, may be stupid, may i create image using imagecreatetruecolor(values) and open it like  fopen("path" ); ?

Comment: You could create an image with any convenient graphics program and open it with, say, `imagecreatefompng()`, but that's not what you asked. You can't use `fopen()` in any sensible way that I can see.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if the sign will work in imagettftext but here it is √. To do it (on mac) you press Alt (option) + J.

Comment: What has this to do with using GD?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the accepted answer - you might also want to delete your comment from below it saying that it doesn't work, otherwise future readers of this question may be misled.